# Appcelerator: Label layout composite in View layout vertical

Tags: layout, appcelerator, composite

I need put a Label above an image. This image is in a view with layout "vertical", and i need that this LABEL put it in the right top of the image, in absolute. How can I do this?

My code:

index.html

```
`<Alloy>
        <View class="col col-2">
                            <ImageView id="images" class="img-thumbnail"  />
                            <Label id="name"></Label>
                            <Label id="price"></Label>
        </View>
</Alloy>
`

    app.tss

    ".col-2":{
        layout: 'vertical',
        width: '49.25%',
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    }
   ".badge":{
    top:0,
    right:0,
    backgroundColor:'green',
    color:'white',
    layout:'composite'
}
```

Alloy.
TITANIUM SDKA: 7.0.0.GA

Comment: can you show a sample screenshot of what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a label at top-right corner above image & along with other views in that vertical layout, then you can wrap your vertical layout in a different view & show image at top-right like this:

```
<Alloy>
    <View width="49.25%" height="Ti.UI.SIZE">

        <!-- now use full width on this view -->
        <View class="col col-2" width="Ti.UI.FILL">
            <ImageView id="images" class="img-thumbnail"  />
            <Label id="name"></Label>
            <Label id="price"></Label>
        </View>

        <Label text="Put your top-right label here" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" top="16" right="16" />
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: Thx Prashant!!. 
I should have thought about doing that before asking